# Listing results with unique column

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to list top 6 race records with unique holder only. I mean a holder gets in the list shouldn't be listed with his another record. I currently use the query below to list top 6 times.

```
mysql> select * from racerecords order by record_time asc, date asc;
+----+---------+------------+-------------+---------------------+----------+
| id | race_id | holder     | record_time | date                | position |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+---------------------+----------+
|  2 |      10 | Stav       |          15 | 2014-08-11 19:43:49 |        1 |
|  1 |      10 | Jennifer   |          15 | 2014-08-13 19:43:19 |        1 |
|  4 |      10 | Jennifer   |          16 | 2014-08-02 19:44:27 |        1 |
|  5 |      10 | Osman      |          17 | 2014-08-04 19:44:57 |        1 |
|  7 |      10 | Gokhan     |          18 | 2014-08-15 19:45:37 |        1 |
|  3 |      10 | MotherLode |          25 | 2014-08-01 19:44:11 |        1 |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+---------------------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see the holder "Jennifer" is listed twice. I want mySQL to skip her after she got in the list. The result I want to be generated is:

```
+----+---------+------------+-------------+---------------------+----------+
| id | race_id | holder     | record_time | date                | position |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+---------------------+----------+
|  2 |      10 | Stav       |          15 | 2014-08-11 19:43:49 |        1 |
|  1 |      10 | Jennifer   |          15 | 2014-08-13 19:43:19 |        1 |
|  5 |      10 | Osman      |          17 | 2014-08-04 19:44:57 |        1 |
|  7 |      10 | Gokhan     |          18 | 2014-08-15 19:45:37 |        1 |
|  3 |      10 | MotherLode |          25 | 2014-08-01 19:44:11 |        1 |
+----+---------+------------+-------------+---------------------+----------+
```

I tried everything. `GROUP BY holder` generates wrong results. It gets the very first record of the holder, even though is not the best. In this table it generates an output like above because **id:1** is the first record I inserted for Jennifer.

How can I generate output a result like above?

Comment: so you want min(id) to determine which record to bring back in the case of multiple records for that holder?

Comment: I don't want to get multiple records for a holder. It is nothing to do with the ID

Comment: so you want `min(record_time)` then?

Comment: Row ID 1 and 4 have the holder 'jennifer'. What logic to you want to use to determine which one to display? Min(ID), because it's the first record?  -edit : -what barranka said...

Comment: I determine by lowest record time and earliest row that is inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desired result can be achieved through this query but it performance intensive. I have reproduced the result in SQLFilddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8ee7/3

```
select * from racerecords
where 
(HOLDER, RECORD_TIME) in (
 select HOLDER,min(RECORD_TIME) from racerecords
group by HOLDER)
```

Seems you have missed to include the Where clause in the sub-query. Try this

```
select * from racerecords
where 
(HOLDER, RECORD_TIME) in (
 select HOLDER,min(RECORD_TIME) from racerecords where race_id =17
group by HOLDER )
And race_id =17
Order by RECORD_TIME
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use distinct clause

```
    SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
    FROM table_name;
```

looks this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: This works but a holder who's got already in the list is being listed after couple of people. At least they are not being listed right after themselves. :D I want holder to be not listed again after once they got in.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can not figure out the problem. You just want to select only once a tuple with the same holder or that tuple must comply with some other constraint?

Comment: A tuple with Top 5 racers. Those 5 times shouldve belong to a different racer so I can know who are the best in this race. The result should give me 5 different names.